# pycharm debugger console can't change the value of a variable

Tags: python, debugging, console, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm community 2019.2.3 and its console in the debugger stopped changing the values of the variables for me.

I've added a print screen of a simple code in which I'm stopping in a breakpoint in line 7. Then I evaluate (Alt Shift E) lines 7 and 8 and the screen prints the new value 'haim'. Afterward, I'm evaluating only line 8 and the value of name comes back to be 'alon' even though I didn't change it.

[image]

Thanks, 
Alon

Answer (score 1):

I ran into exactly the same thing today with 2019.2 Professional.  It had been working fine, and then out of the blue I could no longer change the values of variables in the debugging console.

Reverting back to 2019.1 fixed it for me.

If you're on Ubuntu and using snap to install:

```
sudo snap refresh pycharm-professional --channel=2019.1/stable --classic
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me also.  :) 
It's really weird that this problem happened out of nowhere

Comment: I am pretty sure that the day before it was working just fine, and then yesterday it just started.  I did no system updates or configuration changes.  It just started happening for no apparent cause.